# Как убрать « % link из галереи в WordPress?

Tags: wordpress

Перепробовал несколько галерей wp, везде над галереей выскакивает: « % link. Как этот линк убрать, откуда он?

Answer (score 3):

Напишите название галереи

p.s.:
По моему есть куда более простое решение для организации галерей на wordpress.
Создаем категорию Галерея, для нее в папке вашей темы создаем отдельный шаблон для категории который будет отображать вид записей блочно, 
Ставим плагин [Simple Lightbox](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/simple-lightbox/)

Добавляем записи в категорию Галерея, в эту запись загружаем изображения, изображения вставляем в запись через: [gallery]

и все.

Comment: Пробовал: Shutter Reloaded,Lightbox 2, Image Gallery Reloaded, сейчас WP-SimpleViewer. Везде выдает над галлереей « % link. Это что-то не с галлереями, а с самим WP. В каком направлении искать, а? Спасибо.

Comment: Спасибо за посильную помощь.Разобрался В файле single.php была неверно прописана навигация <?php previous_post_link(.....